# One query for two core data relationships?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have the following data model:

[image]

And I'd like to have a property on the playlist object that points to its list of songs. Right now I have something like:

```
self.songs = [self.playlistMemberships valueForKey:@"song"];
```

But I'm noticing that this is very slow and core data seems to be firing off faults for each individual song. Any thoughts on how to make a single call to pull all the song info? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PlaylistMembership` just seems to get in the way -- can you relate `Playlist` to `Song` directly and cut out the `PlaylistMembership`? I think that'd let Core Data fetch all the songs at once rather than fetching all the memberships and then having to go back to get each song.

If you can't or prefer not to get rid of the membership entity, use `setRelationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching:` to specify that `song` should be fetched along with the membership.

Comment: We want to keep this data structure so that it stays parallel to the database on our server, so changing this isn't really an option.

Comment: @quantka Perhaps my second paragraph will help, then.

Comment: Thanks. I think this worked, haven't quite finished testing it: [fetchRequest setRelationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching: [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"playlistMemberships.song"]];

Comment: You can use the nifty new-ish object literal notation to shorten that: `[fetchRequest setRelationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching: @[@"playlistMemberships.song"]];`